# TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. Whats going on guys?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey guys there is something that requires the upmost assistance. I have a checkbox in a div.

Here is the code:

```
const flareup = document.getElementById("incorrect")
const checker = document.getElementById("clicker")
const maincheck = document.getElementById("maincheck")  
checker.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
    if(event.button == 0){
        console.log("Ok")
        if(checker.checked == true){
            console.log("I am here")
            flareup.style.display = "block"
        }
    if(event.button == 1){
       maincheck.className = "animationclass"
    }
  }
})
```

As can be seen in the code, I want it to show something if it is left clicked and i want it to add an animation class if it is right clicked. My problem is, before I even so much as click it, I get an Uncaught Error, stating that it:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

I am not sure whats wrong. I have made sure my script tag for the javascript file is on top and that i havent misspelled anything or given it a class instead of an ID. For more context, here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>The Verification Game</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./starting.css"></link>
</head>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1f2023aaf1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="verification.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="underneath">
<h2>Are you a human?</h2>
<input type="checkbox" id="realclicker"></input>
</div>
<div id="maincheck">
<h2>Are you a robot?</h2>
<input type="checkbox" id="clicker"></input>
</div>
<div id="incorrect">
<div id="inner">
<h1 class="fancytext">So you are a robot? You can't come here.</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Please help!

Comment: Where and how are you loading your js code? Might be an issue with the DOM not being fully built at the time you're loading the js. Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/how-to-make-javascript-execute-after-page-load as well

Comment: _"I am not sure whats wrong."_ - this: _"my script tag for the javascript file is on top"_ You are trying to select HTML elements, which do not exist yet at this point.

Comment: Besides the already mentioned issues, your HTML is also invalid. You can't have `<script>` tags outside of the `<head>` or `<body>` tags.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. I have solved this now but I now find myself at yet another roadblock. 
```
if(event.button == 1){
    maincheck.className = "animationclass"
    console.log("Is")
    }
```
I have tried rught clicking it but nothing has happened- it wont even print to the console. What'd wrong?